# Clojure sorted-map: find largest key that is less than or equal to x (floor key)

Tags: java, data-structures, clojure, functional-programming

I have a problem where I have some keys that represent time and some values at each time. A small example:

```
 (sorted-map -4 "a" -1 "b" 2 "c" 3 "d")
```

For a given x I would like to find the largest key that is less than or equal to x.

For instance in the Julia DataStructures package there is a sorted dictionary with method such as

> searchsortedlast(sc,k) Argument sc is a SortedDict, SortedMultiDict or
>   SortedSet and k is a key. This routine returns the semitoken of the
>   last item in the container whose key is less than or equal to k. If
>   there is no such key, then the before-start semitoken is returned.
>   Time: O(c log n)

I have been trying to find documentation about a similar function in clojure, but have not been able to find anything.
My naive approach is as follows:

> (apply max (filter #(< % x) (keys (sorted-map -4 "a" -1 "b" 2 "c" 3
>   "d" -10 "e"))))

but I think this is sub-optimal because it first collect all keys, then filters them, creating unnecessary computation.

My questions are
1) is if there is already a function that implements this which I cannot find.
2) If this is not the case, should I search for a Java data structure and use the java datastructure and associated methods
3) is it possible to make my approach lazy so that it is more efficient?

EDIT:

From Java's TreeMap:

> K floorKey(K key) Returns the greatest key less than or equal to the
>   given key, or null if there is no such key.

This is what I am looking for with clojure sorted-map. Should I abandon sorted-map and work with Javas treemap?

EDIT2:

I found this
https://github.com/clojure/data.avl
which provides an alternative sorted-map implementation with "nearest-key" functions

Answer (score 4):

For working with sorted collections like sorted map you can use [`subseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/subseq) and [`rsubseq`](https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/rsubseq).

In your example to find an entry with the largest key equal or less than `x` you can use:

```
(let [m (sorted-map -4 "a" -1 "b" 2 "c" 3 "d")
      x 0]
  (first (rsubseq m <= x)))
;; => [-1 "b"]
```

Comment: Do you know the computational complexity of this lookup? For treemap it would be log n

Comment: Access to elements in `sorted-seq` is log n (http://clojure.org/reference/data_structures#Maps). Actually they are `PersistentTreeMap` underhood (https://github.com/clojure/clojure/blob/clojure-1.8.0/src/clj/clojure/core.clj#L398). `subseq` and `rsubseq` are implemented either as "views" over the original collection for `>`/`>=` and `<`/`<=` respectively or in terms of `take-while` for other test functions.

Comment: I found a new implementation of sorted-map (see EDIT 2). Are there any advantages of doing it your proposed way instead of using the linked implementation?

Comment: Regarding clojure/data.avl it all dependes on your requirements. It's documentation provides detailed information on the differences between `clojure.core` sorted sets and maps (e.g. they provide transient versions, they have faster lookups but slower `assoc`|`update` and add some memory overhead). So it boils down to what your requirements are.